# How to avoid Eclipse/Android losing hardware devices

Tags: android, eclipse

So I usually test om SGII. I then installed HTC Sync to test on an old Android mobile. While this worked, Eclipse has now lost its connection with SGII. How do you maintain multiple hardware devices for testing?

Comment: What OS are you working on? Does "adb devices" list all your devices? I used to have several devices working and could see them, for instance, with Android Commander.

Comment: Windows. I only have one device switched in at a time. It seems restarting the computer helped Eclipse detect I had switced mobile phone. (I had already tried restarting eclipse a few times.)

Answer (score 1):

I see several possibilities, but it really depends on your OS. If you're working on Windows, some possibilities are:

- Try disconnnecting and reconnecting your USB cable. Windows should try to restart the connection to your devices
- type adb kill-server into the command prompt. Afterwards type adb start-server. These commands tell adb to stop and restart (which should be less costly than restarting the computer)
- Reinstall your drivers. It's quite possibly that one (or both of them) are somehow messed up.
- If your connection stopped working when you installed the second device, try reinstalling the first device's drivers. The second's installation might have messed up the first one's